# ZIgbee GNUradio Physical Layer Data Collection Error

Tags: gnuradio-companion, zigbee

I am attempting to collect physical layer data (IQ data) using GNU Radio and two Zigbee devices. The setup involves two Zigbee devices connected to the laptop's ports, as depicted in the image linked below:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ef2jF.jpg). I am using XCTU software to facilitate communication between the two Zigbee devices.

U have set up GNU Radio using the  I used [WIME Zigbee Project](https://www.wime-project.net/tutorials/zigbee/), as shown in the image attached below:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A7UqC.png)

However, I'm encountering an issue. While I can observe messages between the two Zigbee devices in the "sensor.pcap" file using Wireshark, I'm unable to visualize this data in the QT GUI SINK; it remains empty. Additionally, when I attempt to collect physical layer data, the output is also empty.

My question is, how can I successfully collect data after the "IEEE 802.15.4 oqpsk phy" layer block?